# Access home directory on Linux from macOS over NFS

Tags: osx, nfs, raspbian

I want to mount directories on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Stretch and access on macOS using nfs.

`/etc/exports` on the Pi contains

```
/home/pi    *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

I can successfully mount the share on macOS with

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport,rw IP:/home/pi mountpoint
```

This mounts the files as user 1000, and I can access the files, but not write or delete.

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o noowners,resvport,rw IP:/home/pi mountpoint
```

Mounts the files as current macOS user, but I still can't write or delete.

The `uid` of the macOS user is 501.
Ideally I would like to configure the system to allow my Mac user to have equivalent access to the pi user, without opening the whole `home` directory to all.

Comment: Can you run NFS v4 on each system? That will let you specify ID mapping on the NFS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the hint by Mark Plotnick, reading the very confusing man pages and lots of experimentation I finally got it to work using the following in `/etc/exports`

```
/home/pi        *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/home/pi        zaphod.local(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

`zaphod.local` is my Mac, and this maps the `uid` and `gid` to those of the pi user.

Other `pi` users have their normal access, but any others can only read files.